# New Facebook picture url format is not visible anymore on some Android Phones

Tags: javascript, android, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I'm using Javascript (Cordova/PhoneGap Build) to get some profile pictures using the Facebook Graph API. Here is a sample code:

```
FB.api("/v1.0/" + tmp_fb_id + "/picture?redirect=0&height=" + pic_height + "&type=normal&width=" + pic_width, function (response) {

        if (response && !response.error) {
            var json_data = response.data;
            $("#img-1").attr("src", json_data.url);
        }
```

This worked fine until recently. On some phones, the image doesn't show up anymore, and I figured out it's because of the url format that I get from facebook. Some urls look like this:

```
https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xaf1/l/t31.0-1/c435.168.1177.1030/s320x320/219800_10150165625678127_6471352_o.jpg
```

And they are FINE on all phones. But sometimes, the response url that I get from facebook looks like this (notice the extra variables after .jpg):

```
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/c0.20.320.280/p320x320/10004054_10152380867008400_6911804500751766609_n.jpg?oh=f7845490992f046f29b99384f2c37022&oe=54855B4B&__gda__=1421641326_c476878a926031e9d295f33da3683d79
```

And these images do not show up on many Android Phones (it's a "?" as if the image is broken). If I remove the variables after "?", the image won't show up anymore (in the desktop browser it says "An error occurred while processing your request."), so it's definitely needed. Any idea what could be done to be able to show these images on ALL phones?